# WPF: How to ignore defined style for concrete control

Tags: wpf

I have the Rectangle control style (for the type of Rectangle) defined in resource dictionary and it reflects the style for a Menu control also.

How to ignore these settings for Menu and leave it for (just) Rectangle? - Drawing purposes in canvas .... The Rectangle control is added to canvas dynamically from code behind. In main window is dockpanel, grid, menu, textblock and canvas controls. Style for rectangle also harm style properties for Menu (needed to keep the default style).

Thanks for advice

**Main window controls:**

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="True">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="21" Name="menu" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=menuStyle}">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Open image" Command="{Binding DoCommand}" CommandParameter="OpenImage"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding DoCommand}" CommandParameter="Exit"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
            <RadioButton Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Text selection" GroupName="ObjectType" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ObjectType, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=RadioButtonTypeConverter}, ConverterParameter=Text}" />
            <RadioButton Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Picture selection" GroupName="ObjectType" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ObjectType, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=RadioButtonTypeConverter}, ConverterParameter=Picture}" />
        </Grid>
        <pt:PropertyControl DockPanel.Dock="Right" SelectedObject="{Binding SelectedObject}" MinWidth="150"/>

        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="100" Margin="5" Background="#FFF9F9F9">

        </TextBlock>
        <Canvas Name="canvas" MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown" Background="White" Width="{Binding ElementName=ImgEdit, Path=Width}" Height="{Binding ElementName=ImgEdit, Path=Height}" MinWidth="300" MinHeight="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseMove="canvas_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonUp="canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp" >

            <Image x:Name="ImgEdit" Source="{Binding BackgroundImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
```

**Code of my Style resource dictionary:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" >
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow" />
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.2"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: To understand the problem, please, could you show the code?

Comment: I updated the question by code samples. Thanks for help

Comment: What is the style for the menu - `menuStyle`? I understand you want to draw a rectangle around the image and not immediately?

Comment: Hi, I leave it empty in style resource (there is just node created, because I was thinking that this can help). But for the case if you ignore the style name and Menu is using default settings, the rectangle style is influencing the MenuItems of Menu (according to Rectangle style definition upon).
Is there any option how to set Rectangle style definition just for Rectangle UI object and have a default for Menu?

Comment: You set for `Rectangle` height and width? Do you want to draw the rectangle *over* the `Image`?

Comment: The rectangle H and W is set in code behind - so yes, and yes :)